# How to run a basic C program in vscode

Tags: c

I'm an absolute beginner in C programming and I'm trying to write a simple program to get two integer values, then print out the sum.
I installed vs code and the required extensions.
gcc is also installed on my computer.
I opened a new file with .c in the end and wrote down the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int integer1;
   int integer2;

   printf("Enter a number \n");
   scanf("%d", &integer1);

   printf("Enter a number \n");
   scanf("%d", &integer2);

   int sum;
   sum = integer1 + integer2;

   printf(sum);
}
```

I'm clicking on the run button but I don't know where i should input the required values.
Also I get this warning:

incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]

I'm using visual studio code version 1.71.2

Comment: You need a constant format definition in your last "printf".  E.G.  printf("%d\n", sum);

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code a little bit. You have to write `printf("%d", sum);` instead of `printf(sum);`